# FTP UPLOADS CONFIGURATIONS

Tags: php, ftp, warnings

Warning: ftp_put(): Can't open that file: Is a directory in *** on line 183

Warning: ftp_put(): Can't open that file: Is a directory in *** on line 185

183 line: if (ftp_put($ftp_conn_id, "/".$dir . "/$nameimage/", $ftp_temp_img, FTP_BINARY)) {

185 line: if (ftp_put($ftp_conn_id, "/".$dirthumb . "/$nameimage/", $ftp_temp_thumb, FTP_BINARY)) {

Who could it be bad? How would it be possible to correct the work?

Comment: `Is a directory` means that the file you tried to upload is a directory. Plain FTP can't do recursive directory uploads

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 if (ftp_put($ftp_conn_id, "/".$dir . "/$nameimage/", $ftp_temp_img, FTP_BINARY)) {
```

Into

```
 if (ftp_put($ftp_conn_id, "/".$dir . "/$nameimage", $ftp_temp_img, FTP_BINARY)) {
```